# Not sure why OSMnx is not working despite being installed

Tags: installation, openstreetmap, osmnx

So I've been trying to work OSMnx. I've installed it using conda, and when I run to check the install, it tells me this, which means it's installed. (If I'm correct).

```
(ox) Owens-Air:Helloworld owencooper$ conda list osmnx packages in environment at /Users/owencooper/opt/anaconda3/envs/ox:
```

Name Version Build Channel osmnx 1.0.1 pyhd3deb0d_0 conda-forge

Having got this showing OSMnx is installed, when running the following line, It comes out with 'Import "osmnx" could not be resolved'. I'm not sure why this is the case, I have activated ox, but not really sure how this impacts this.

```
import osmnx as ox 
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you running your python code? Via the python interpreter in the terminal? Or via Jupyter? Or what? In your computer's terminal window, try running `conda activate ox && python -c "import osmnx as ox; print(ox.__version__)"`. What happens?

Comment: So in the python interpreter it comes up with the error, however when i run your example through jupyter it seems to work! Is there a way to get it to work in the python interpreter? When i run that in the python terminal, it comes out with: 1.0.1

Comment: You said "When i run that in the python terminal, it comes out with: 1.0.1". What does "python terminal" mean here? The python interpreter in the terminal? If so, it sounds like it's working.